# Add chunk of code without executing it

Tags: r, knitr

In **knitr**, is there any option that allows code to be inserted without being executed? I only want the code to appear in the document with the same style than other **knitr** code chunks.

I am particularly interested in the options for LaTeX in a .Rnw document.

Comment: use the chunk option `eval = FALSE`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like @Ramnath commented, this can be achieved using the `eval = FALSE` chunk option.